# How to find distance between two anagrams in a string

Tags: java

Requirement: Given string, find distance between all occurrences of anagrams of strings
Example: "programmerxxddporragmmerbbffprogrammer"
String pat = "programmer";

Expected output: 4
distance between two palidromes of "programmer" is 4

```
//Java program to search all anagrams 
//of a pattern in a text 
public class Pattern
{ 
    static final int MAX = 256; 

    // This function returns true if contents 
    // of arr1[] and arr2[] are same, otherwise 
    // false. 
    static boolean compare(char arr1[], char arr2[]) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) 
            if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) 
                return false; 
        return true; 
    } 

    // This function search for all permutations 
    // of pat[] in txt[] 
    static void search(String pat, String txt) 
    { 
        int M = pat.length(); 
        int N = txt.length(); 

        // countP[]: Store count of all 
        // characters of pattern 
        // countTW[]: Store count of current 
        // window of text 
        char[] countP = new char[MAX]; 
        char[] countTW = new char[MAX]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) 
        { 
            (countP[pat.charAt(i)])++; 
            (countTW[txt.charAt(i)])++; 
        } 

        // Traverse through remaining characters 
        // of pattern 
        for (int i = M; i < N; i++) 
        { 
            // Compare counts of current window 
            // of text with counts of pattern[] 
            if (compare(countP, countTW)) 
                System.out.println("Found at Index " + 
                                        (i - M)); 

            // Add current character to current 
            // window 
            (countTW[txt.charAt(i)])++; 

            // Remove the first character of previous 
            // window 
            countTW[txt.charAt(i-M)]--; 
        } 

        // Check for the last window in text 
        if (compare(countP, countTW)) {
            System.out.println("Found at Index " + 
                                    (N - M)); 
            System.out.println(N-M-M);
        }
    } 

    /* Driver program to test above function */
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        String txt = "programmerxxddporragmmerbbffprogrammer"; 
        String pat = "programmer"; 
        search(pat, txt); 
    } 
}
```

I am required to print first instance of the difference between two anagrams. In my case, 4. My code is printing for the final string like this:

Answer (score 0):

So your code was doing well at finding the palindromes. So I adapted it to track where it found the last palindrome so that when it finds a new one, it can take the distance between, which would be the indices of each minus the length of the pattern (I chose to track all differences, but you could suppress that). Here is the code adapted to report the distance each time (the rest is unchanged).

```
//Java program to search all anagrams 
//of a pattern in a text 
public class Pattern{
static final int MAX = 256; 

// This function returns true if contents 
// of arr1[] and arr2[] are same, otherwise 
// false. 
static boolean compare(char arr1[], char arr2[]) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) 
        if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) 
            return false; 
    return true; 
} 

// This function search for all permutations 
// of pat[] in txt[] 
static void search(String pat, String txt) 
{ 
    int M = pat.length(); 
    int N = txt.length();
    int lastFoundIndex = -1;

    // countP[]: Store count of all 
    // characters of pattern 
    // countTW[]: Store count of current 
    // window of text 
    char[] countP = new char[MAX]; 
    char[] countTW = new char[MAX]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) 
    { 
        (countP[pat.charAt(i)])++; 
        (countTW[txt.charAt(i)])++; 
    } 

    // Traverse through remaining characters 
    // of pattern 
    for (int i = M; i < N; i++) 
    { 
        // Compare counts of current window 
        // of text with counts of pattern[] 
        if (compare(countP, countTW)) {
            System.out.println("Found at Index " + 
                                    (i - M)); 
                                    if (lastFoundIndex==-1){
            lastFoundIndex = i-M;}
            else {
            System.out.println("Distance between is: "+(i-M-lastFoundIndex-pat.length()));
            lastFoundIndex = i-M;

        }
        }


        // Add current character to current 
        // window 
        (countTW[txt.charAt(i)])++; 

        // Remove the first character of previous 
        // window 
        countTW[txt.charAt(i-M)]--; 
    } 

    // Check for the last window in text 
    if (compare(countP, countTW)) {
        System.out.println("Found at Index " + 
                                (N - M));
        if (lastFoundIndex==-1){
            lastFoundIndex = N-M;
        }
        else{

            System.out.println("Distance between is: "+(N-M-lastFoundIndex-pat.length()));
            lastFoundIndex = N-M;
        }
    }
} 

/* Driver program to test above function */
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    String txt = "programmerxxddporragmmerbbffprogrammer"; 
    String pat = "programmer"; 
    search(pat, txt); 
} 
}
```

output is

```
Found at Index 0
Found at Index 14
Distance between is: 4
Found at Index 28
Distance between is: 4
```

REVISION:
I then went back and implemented the whole thing differently, possibly less efficiently, but easier for me to follow (output was the same).

```
//Java program to search all anagrams 
//of a pattern in a text 
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Pattern {
    // Method to sort a string alphabetically (from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-a-string-in-java-2-different-ways/) 
    public static String sortString(String inputString) {
        // convert input string to char array 
        char tempArray[] = inputString.toCharArray();

        // sort tempArray 
        Arrays.sort(tempArray);

        // return new sorted string 
        return new String(tempArray);
    }

    // This function searches for all permutations 
    // of pat in txt 
    static void search(String pat, String txt) {
        String patSorted = sortString(pat); //sort the pattern once
        int M = pat.length();
        int N = txt.length();
        int lastFoundIndex = -1; //last place found
        for (int i = 0; N - i >= M; i++) { //while there are still enough remaining characters from this index on in txt
            if (sortString(txt.substring(i, i + M)).equals(patSorted)) {
                System.out.println("Found at Index " + i);
                if (lastFoundIndex == -1) {
                    lastFoundIndex = i;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Distance between is: " + (i - lastFoundIndex - M));
                    lastFoundIndex = i;
                }
            }

        }

    }



    /* Driver program to test above function */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String txt = "programmerxxddporragmmerbbffprogrammer";
        String pat = "programmer";
        search(pat, txt);
    }
}
```